How do I point to specific Python libraries?
In our environment Ansible is installed on one of the servers that I have access to. However, I do not have access to root so I can only install packages etc as my account.
I installed the packages like requests, pywinrm and few others as my user in a venv but when I execute ansible, it does not pick these up.
In a nutshell the issue is:

Packages do not get displayed in system python (the one that Ansible is pointing to)
/usr/bin/python3.9 -m pip list


Package display just fine in venv (this is under my venv)
python -m pip list


End result is that I receive error
winrm or requests is not installed: No module named 'winrm'



Is anyone aware of a fix for this issue?
Tried specifying ansible_python_interpreter at the command line while invoking ansible but that did not help.

“Tried specifying ansible_python_interpreter at the command line while invoking ansible” – how, and what was the output?

ansible ....  -e 'ansible_python_interpreter=/my/python/location'
Output was the same error.

How do you execute your python script in an ansible playbook?

For example, if you run it as a command
  ansible.builtin.script:
    cmd: <path_to_yuor_venv>/bin/python3 <your_python_script>.py```

Install Ansible in your venv and use it from there. It will pick up the libs you installed in the same place.

@Zeitounator tried that but ran out of space. Need to engage unix admin to ask for more space.. not sure how long that will take. Can you please post this as an answer so that I can accept it ?
